# Okta Pass list of roles instead of single value?

Tags: okta

Currently, our TestCo Okta is able to pass ‘testrole’ with one of a few different values, e.g. ‘admin’ or ‘user.’ If a user has multiple ‘testrole’ attributes (based on group membership) then Okta has a precedence order that determines which one ‘testrole’ value it will return.

We need to be able to handle passing a list of roles from IdP to Cognito to our API. For example, a string of ‘admin, user, readonly, section-admin’.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a "groups" or "roles" claim that contains all the groups information. To do this, log in to your Okta developer account, then navigate to **API** > **Authorization Servers**, and click on the `default` server. Click the **Claims** tab and **Add Claim**. Name it `groups` (or `roles`), and include it in the ID Token. Set the value type to `Groups` and set the filter to be a Regex of `.*`. Click **Create**.

[image: Add Claim Dialog]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer but I don't think this will work since we need to pass this information in the SAML assertion to cognito, our backend doesn't hit the okta authentication server itself (if I'm saying that right our tech lead explained it and I'm not sure I got it right)